# Django get average (string)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I have moods like: family,Dating . I need to get which mood average used by user.

**Models.py**

```
class Mood(models.Model):
    moods=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='moods/', blank=True, null=True)
    count=models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True,default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.moods)
class UserMood(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mood=models.ForeignKey(Mood,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**views.py**

```
    user_moods=UserMood.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    user_stats['average_mood']=''
```

need to get average mode based on UserMood entries.

Comment: This is the average of the `count`?

Comment: I need string(mood)  based on average count of entries in UserMood . I need which mood in maximum avg used by user

Comment: Well there is no such thing as an *average* string... We can generate the string of the mood that occurred most common, etc.

Comment: I have moods like: family,Dating . I need to get which mood average used by user.

Comment: @TURANSHARMA: but how would you define such "average". Say a user has five "family" moods, and three "dating", then what is the average?

Comment: It may be max count of moods can you tell how can i get which mood has max count

Answer (score 0):

You can get the most common mood of a user, by specifying it as:

```
from django.db.models import Count

top_mood=Mood.objects.filter(
    usermood__user=request.user
).annotate(
    cnt=Count('usermood')
).order_by('-cnt').first()
```

Given the `User` has at least such `usermood`, if not, then `top_mood` is `None`. The `top_mood` is thus a `Mood` object, and you can query for the `top_mood.moods` to get the "name" of the mood.

> **Note**: I advice to fix the nomenclature, and for example rename `moods` to `name`. Your `UserMood` seems to be a *many-to-many* relation, so you might want to fix this.